# How to convert an array vector to a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matrix, vector

I have a simple question:
I have a vector `testv` of dim. `(1000X784)`. I want to convert some of its rows (the misclassified members) to a matrix of dim. `(28X28)`. I do the following:

```
    x = zeros(28,28);
    idx = find(labtrain ~= labtest); % the index of the misclassified members. 
    for k = 1:length(idx)  % plot the misclassified members
        x(:) = testv(idx,:);
        figure
        image(x)
      end
```

But I get the following error:

```
In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.
```

I can not figure out how to get rid of that.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried "[reshape](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)" ?

Reshape a 1-by-10 vector into a 5-by-2 matrix:

```
A = 1:10;
B = reshape(A,[5,2])

B =

 1     6
 2     7
 3     8
 4     9
 5    10
```

Comment: I tried the following : `
x = zeros(28,28);
idx = find(labtrain ~= labtest);

for k = 1:length(idx)
    x = reshape(testv(idx,:),[28,28]);
    figure
    image(x)
    
end` This time I get this error: `Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.`

Comment: So strange, because when I try the following in command line: `x = reshape(testv(9,:),[28,28]);` It goes fine.

Comment: my idx vector is `[9
         12.00
         36.00
         40.00
         51.00
         68.00
         80.00
         84.00
        105.00
        106.00
        183.00]`

Comment: Perhaps you could tell the others where the problem was, in case someone else needs to know.

Comment: Sure, I had to choose idx component by component, as it is a vector: x = reshape(testv(**idx(k,1)**,:),[28,28]);